# filter_condition_callback function not called in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, grid, filter, custom-column-grid

I'm adding a **custom column** (from a custom table) to an admin grid with an **observer**, and the filtering/sorting doesn't work. Adding the **'filter_condition_callback'** to my column doesn't work, **the function is never called**.

I've seen other similar questions but none of them had this particular problem, or they were never answered.

---

I've made a module that modifies the admin_user grid.

It contains an observer linked to these events :

```
    <core_collection_abstract_load_before>
        <observers>
            <beforeCollectionLoad>
                <class>Namespace_Adminextra_Model_Observers_Users</class>
                <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
            </beforeCollectionLoad>
        </observers>
    </core_collection_abstract_load_before>

    <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
            <add_an_field>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Namespace_Adminextra_Model_Observers_Users</class>
                <method>appendContent</method>
            </add_an_field>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_block_html_before>
```

So the beforeCollectionLoad method is called so I can join my custom column (from a custom table, not an attribute) :

```
public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }
    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_User_Collection) {
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('adminextra' => 'digitagri_adminextra'),
            'adminextra.user_id = main_table.user_id',
            array(
                'is_advisor' => 'adminextra.is_advisor',
                'phone' => 'adminextra.phone',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This successfully seems to add the column to the collection.
The observer first calls the function appendContent, which checks the current grid :

```
public function appendContent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    if (!isset($block)) {
        return $this;
    }
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid) {
        $this->appendCustomColumns($block);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Then the column is added :

```
public function appendCustomColumns($grid){
    $grid->addColumnAfter('is_advisor', array(
        'header' => 'Conseiller',
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '50',
        'index' => 'is_advisor',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options'   => array('1' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Oui'), '0' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Non')),
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this,'_filterIsAdvisor'),
    ), 'is_active');
    $grid->sortColumnsByOrder();
}
```

The column is added and the values are displayed, the 'options' acts as a renderer and correctly displays '1' as Oui and '0' as Non. But the filtering and sorting don't work. No error, no exceptions, it does nothing.

The function called in 'filter_condition_callback' never seems to be called either. I've put a Mage::log to check :

```
protected function _filterIsAdvisor($collection, $column){
    Mage::log('works?',null,'test.log',true);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Filtering and sorting seem incredibly finicky, especially since i'm joining a column from a custom table and not an attribute.

Comment: There is another way to add/ remove columns from grid via XML. please check https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl .

Comment: I've seen this multiple times. I'll check it out if there is absolutely no other way, I would rather find a "normal" way to do this first.

Comment: I have the same issue everything works just fine, only the `filter_condition_callback` is completely ignored and rather when filtering it tries to find the product attribute the regular way by `invalid attribute name: filtered_by_name`

Comment: FYI https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/magento-grid-filter-condition-callback-ignored-in-magento-ver-1-9-4-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a code breaking change

Read

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/882

And apply

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/887

Please mark as the answer if correct

Comment: This works .....